# index scan in select statement

Tags: sql-server, optimization

While testing query:

```
select AccountID, SchemaID, Name, Description, CurrentVersion 
from [test].[dbo].[FormSchema] 
where SchemaID like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]%'
```

After running execution plan it is showing clustered index scan with 100% cost.  There is one clustered index on column schemaId.

My question is how can I make it index seek rather than scan?

Comment: The broad issue here is that your regex is not "sargable."  Exactly what is and isn't sargable varies by platform, but as a heuristic, you could ask "could I quickly find someone in the phone book with this criteria?"  The answer is "no," you'd need to look at every entry - in other words, an index scan.  If your filter was `SchemaID = 'Bob'`, you could skip to the Bs and flip a few pages left or right until you got to the Bobs - an index seek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SchemaID like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]%'` is going to be problematic no matter what you do.

Having said that, if you added an index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_FormSchema 
ON dbo.FormSchema(SchemaID) 
INCLUDE (AccountID, SchemaID, Name, Description, CurrentVersion);
```

And change the query to:

```
WHERE SchemaID like '[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]%'
```

you *might* get an index seek.

Having said that, an index scan is not inherently a bad thing.  In fact, SQL Server is choosing to do an index scan because it believes that is the fastest way to get your results.